# Bean and method name vs lambda in Spring Integration with Java DSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

is there a way in Spring Integration Java Dsl to make this:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow serviceFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from("inputChannel")
        .handle(File.class, (p,h) -> someService.someMethod(p))
        .channel("someChannel")
        .get();
}
```

behave like this:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow serviceFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from("inputChannel")
        .handle("someService","someMethod")
        .channel("someChannel")
        .get();
}
```

when it comes to exception handling?

first version throws:

```
2015-06-03 23:30:42.912 ERROR 6251 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.springframework.integration.dsl.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:129)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:71)
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error from service
at com.lukzar.SomeService.someMethod(SomeService.java:15)
at com.lukzar.IntegrationConfiguration.lambda$serviceFlow$1(IntegrationConfiguration.java:48)
at com.lukzar.IntegrationConfiguration$$Lambda$2/1367672657.handle(Unknown Source)
(...)
```

and version with beanName and methodName throws:

```
2015-06-03 23:27:45.841 ERROR 6177 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: error from service
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:78)
at org.springframework.integration.dsl.support.BeanNameMessageProcessor.processMessage(BeanNameMessageProcessor.java:57)
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error from service
at com.lukzar.SomeService.someMethod(SomeService.java:15)
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If, by "behave like" you mean make the `error from service` exception the first `cause`, then we could look at removing the `InvocationTargetException` from the stack trace. That would make the underlying exception the `MessageHandlingException`'s `cause`.

If you mean make the stack trace absolutely identical, then no.

If you mean the former, then please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT) against the `JavaDSL` component and we'll take a look.

Comment: Yes, i ment it like the first one. I opened a JIRA issue.